# JavaScript event delegation `this` to delegated elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to `addClass` to the relevant delegated class: `['.ping', '.pong', '.pingpong']`. These classes are dynamically added. Example `mouseenter` on `.ping` should `.addClass('bg-highlight')` to `.ping`. How do I properly target the class?

Attempts:

```
$('#result').on('mouseenter', ['.ping', '.pong', '.pingpong'], function(event){
  $( event.delegateTarget ).addClass('bg-highlight');
```

Problem: `event.delegateTarget` renders `addClass` on `#result`

```
$('#result').on('mouseenter', ['.ping', '.pong', '.pingpong'], function(){
  $( this ).addClass('bg-highlight');
```

Problem: `this` renders `addClass` on `#result`

Comment: instead of `['.ping', '.pong', '.pingpong']` it should be `'.ping, .pong, .pingpong'`

Comment: how about _e.target_ ?

Comment: You're wrong, `this` is the element that the events originates from when using jQuery,  the issue is probably something else, most likely the wrong use of an array instead of a string for the delegated selector.

Comment: **As shown by my answer, `this` is properly targeting the intended element.**

Comment: @PeterKA ok very good thanks Kartikeya answered the same before you. No need to downvote the question and **bold** your text.

Comment: Good point! If you can edit the opening paragraph to indicate that you want all children `.ping, .pong, .pingpong` to get class `.bg-highlight` when any one of `.ping, .pong, .pingpong` is hovered, I'll un-downvote the question.

Comment: @PeterKA it is in the FIRST sentence: **I want to addClass to the relevant delegated class:** Perhaps you overlooked this :)

Comment: Usually an example is meant to clarify and amplify a statement; I am not sure that this was the case with your example.

Comment: Ok @PeterKA feel free to edit the question yourself if you think it will help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :-

```
$('#result').on('mouseenter', '*' , function(){
   var arr = ['ping', 'pong', 'pingpong'];
   $.each(arr, function(i, elem) { 
     $('.'+elem).addClass('bg-highlight'); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Yep this is what I needed thanks @Kartikeya -- Yeah your edit is actually what I had modded too. Funny. What had me stuck was the []

Comment: This is going to be very expensive performance-wise as it targets all children of `#result`.

Comment: @Peter it's supposed to target all children of #result.

Comment: ***Example mouseenter on `.ping` should `.addClass('bg-highlight')` to `.ping`*** ... So why do you add the class to **ALL** children when one is hovered? A quick demo should reveal that.

Comment: @FábïøAnšęlmò, I take you're the best person to tell what you want.

Comment: @PeterKA...i think you have correctly pointed in your above comment that you misread the question and you are increasing unnecessary comments here ... the fiddle which you have provided is working absolutely fine as the OP wants...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do it:

```
var clsArr = ['.ping', '.pong', '.pingpong'],
    clsStr = clsArr.join(',');
$('#result').on('mouseenter', clsStr, function(){
    $( this ).addClass('bg-highlight');
});
```

```js
    var clsArr = ['.ping', '.pong', '.pingpong'],
        clsStr = clsArr.join(',');
    $('#result').on('mouseenter', clsStr, function(){
        $( this ).addClass('bg-highlight');
    });
```

```css
.bg-highlight {
  color:yellow;
  background-color:black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
<div class="ping">PING</div>
<div class="pong">PONG</div>
<div class="pingpong">PINGPONG</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: my first answer was the same what you have posted but `.ping,.pong,.pingpong` is not fixed it is stored in an array

Comment: Update coming up shortly. @Kartikeya?